# Address secondary external storage on Android < 4.4

Tags: android, storage

I'm a little bit confused about using external storage to save some data.

According to the documentation:

> Sometimes, a device that has allocated a partition of the internal memory for use as the external storage may also offer an SD card slot. When such a device is running Android 4.3 and lower, the getExternalFilesDir() method provides access to only the internal partition and your app cannot read or write to the SD card. [...]

As far as I understood, an external memory can either be a partition in the internal memory of the phone used as "external memory" (**primary external storage**) or a removable SD card (**secondary external storage**).

My doubts are:

1. Prior to Android 4.4, is there a portable way to address specifically the secondary external storage (i.e. the SD card)? If the answer is NO (because I think this is the answer reading previous posts), what happens if the primary external storage becomes full? Does the Android framework start to write on the secondary external memory?
2. Always following the Android's doc:

> Beginning with API Level 8, you can allow your application to be installed on the external storage (for example, the device's SD card).

In this case, with *external storage* does the doc mean the secondary external storage or not?

Comment: "is there a portable way to address specifically the secondary external storage" -- there is nothing in the Android SDK for [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) prior to Android 4.4, and I would not consider the script-kiddie solutions you've probably seen to be reliable. "Does the Android framework start to write on the secondary external memory" -- no.

Comment: "with external storage does the doc mean the secondary external storage or not?" -- originally it meant what you are calling the primary external storage. Android 6.0 extended this to removable storage, albeit only for dedicated use (i.e., you cannot use a microSD card to store apps *and* store photos).

Comment: So prior to Android 4.4, what was SD card used for? I am confused from what you said, because I have a phone with android 4.2.1 and on my external sd card I have saved photos, musics, whatsapp data and so on...how could their own apps write on the sd card?

Comment: "what was SD card used for?" -- device manufacturers can, at their discretion, offer apps that work with removable storage. On Android 4.4+, the Storage Access Framework allows apps to work with storage more generally, which can include removable media. "how could their own apps write on the sd card?" -- either the apps shipped with the device (and so knew what the rules were for working with that device's removable storage), or the developers use the unreliable options that I mentioned previously.

Comment: Is there a way to switch the two storage options? I mean making the SD card as primary external storage and viceversa? Second question, does the system's media scanner look in both locations?

Comment: "I mean making the SD card as primary external storage and viceversa?" -- not usually. Even if it is, that's up to the user and the device manufacturer, not app developers. "does the system's media scanner look in both locations?" -- it should, which is why the best way to work with "files" is not to work with files, but instead work with streams published by providers like `MediaStore`. Then, you don't care whether the file is on external storage, removable storage, etc. You just use the data.